# Как удалить макс. и мин. значения в списке, когда их имеется несколько?

Tags: python, массивы

Есть код, смысл удалить минимальные и максимальные значения в списке.
Например, есть список [6, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 2] и надо удалить все единички и сёмерки, чтобы было [6, 2, 2]. Я могу найти их индексы, но как их удалить?

```
a=list(map(int, input().split()))
max_value=max(a)
min_value=min(a)
max_index=[]
min_index=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]==max_value:
        max_index.append(i)
    elif a[i]==min_value:
        min_index.append(i)
print(max_index)
print(min_index)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно реализовать с помощью фильтра. Мин и макс делаем в виде кортежа, в условии фильтра проверяем, что значение не находится в этом кортеже.

```
lst = [6, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 2]
minmax = min(lst), max(lst)
lst = list(filter(lambda x: x not in minmax, lst))
print(lst)
```

Аналогично с помощью спискового включения:

```
lst = [6, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 2]
minmax = min(lst), max(lst)
lst = [x for x in lst if x not in minmax]
print(lst)
```

```
[6, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [6, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 2]
```

**способ 1:**

```
res = [v for v in lst if min(lst) < v < max(lst)]
```

**способ 1.1 (побыстрее):**

```
r = min(lst)
s = max(lst)
res = [v for v in lst if r < v < s]
```

**способ 1.2 (1.1 через фильтр):**

```
res = [*filter(lambda v: r < v < s, lst)]
```